# Keep failing with error " Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated "

Tags: reactjs, azure

I am using Azure static Web Apps to host my React website.

And I keep facing the error below.

```
yarn run v1.22.10
$ react-scripts build
Creating an optimized production build...
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
npx browserslist@latest --update-db

Treating warnings as errors because process.env.CI = true.

Most CI servers set it automatically.

Failed to compile.
```

I have tried `npx browserslist@latest --update-db` for several times but it keep send run failed message to me.

[and here is the entire error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aY33.png)

Comment: I dont think it is an issue with azure static web app https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6708

Comment: @Sajeetharan Hi thanks for the reply ! Just figure this out through the post ( https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer/issues/1184 ) `npm i npm-update-all -g` fixed this.

Comment: Don’t add solved to the title. If your found a solution yourself write an answer and accept it.

Comment: @t.niese Thank you ! First time posting questions, still need to learn a lot ... By the way, I got `you can accept your own answers in 2 days`. Is that normal ?

Comment: @t.niese - Curious to know more about your comment regarding not to add "solved" to the title. Appreciate if you can explain. Thanks.

Comment: @GauravMantri Perhaps this will effect the searching results, cause I just found out that problem with correct answer selected will make the answers box turn into full green instead of only green outlined.

Comment: @GauravMantri because there is the feature to accept an answer, so “solved” is unnecessary and just adds noise. Especially if everyone writes it in a different way. And I often search for questions with no accepted answered to check if I can answers them.

Comment: @t.niese much thanks for the explanation !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for all who are facing this problem ,
checkout this post  [Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated #1184](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer/issues/1184)

using `npm i npm-update-all -g` to update all outdated files can solve this issue

Comment: Yes. Also want to point out that this problem would appear on all CI/CD platforms, not just Azure Static Web Apps, because warnings are treated as errors in those environments. Locally, this warning still appears but doesn’t break the build.

Comment: @AnthonyChu thank you for the remind ! it does help a lot

Comment: `yarn upgrade` if using yarn.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem in my Vue App.And in my case,`yarn upgrade` helps a lot.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30169043)

Answer (score 0):

In my case cleaning `node_modules` folder and reinstalling the packages helped:

```bash
# From the root of the repo
rm -rf node_modules
npx browserslist@latest --update-db
```

If you have multiple `package.json` files in the repository, [check out how to clean all node_modules recursively](https://sebhastian.com/remove-node-modules/)